# How to reinstall Ubuntu over my old installation?

Tags: installation, boot

I have a machine that came with 12.04 LTS pre-installed. After working seamlessly, it sat unused for a bit and now will not boot properly. I've searched for fixes, but none has worked. I'd like to just do a "clean install" of 12.04.3.

I have created a bootable DVD. Once I'm in the boot menu and boot from the DVD, is there anything else I need to do? Will the installer "overwrite" what is already installed or do I need to remove the old OS first? I won't end up with two partitions, one with the old broken OS and one with the newly installed one, will I?

Please use as simple as language as possible when answering.

Comment: The existing Ubuntu installation should be detected, and you'll be offered to replace it. The screen may look something [like this](http://i1-news.softpedia-static.com/images/extra/LINUX/large/ubuntu1104installation-large_003.jpg). Good luck reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

What would you want to happen.

The installation will provide you with a few options - one of them to re-install, the other to use existing space and install there. Of course, you can always choose the custom way of doing things your own way, but there is a risk is you are not sure how to handle the partitions.

The re-install will remove and overwrite your partitions, along with any data you have on them, so tread carefully there. You won't have too remove the old os.